# Getting error while importing Mapping on Informatica

Tags: data-warehouse, informatica

Error wile import mapping on Informatica

When I try to import mapping on Informatica, I encounters an error as I explained below, so that I couldn't get the workflow also

> Completed importing selected objects, there were some errors, please see output for more information,
>
> Validating Target definition TGT_TBL_FUNCTION
>   06/03/16 10:45:40****Importing source definition:Credit_trans_txt
>     Validating source definition Credit_trans_txt
>   06/03/16 10:45:40****Importing source definition: src_sample
>
> Object referenced by the shortcut does not exist in the original folder
>   Object will be imported under the current folder
>   06/03/16 10:45:40****Importing mapping:m_sample
>
> **Error: Could not find transformation definition for :Flat file src_sample
>   **Failed to import:m_sample**

Kindly provide me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual reason is this 'shortcut does not exist in the original folder'. So source Flat file src_sample doesnt exist in your target repository's folder.
To elaborate, in your source repo, you may have a folder named 'shared' where this file definition src_sample exists. And you used it as shortcut in your own folder (say 'myfolder') where m_sample resides. While copying to target repository same shortcut should exist.

Depending on situation, solution may be like this -

1. Folder 'shared' may not be shared in target repository. Modify it as shared and then check if src_sample exists or not. If yes, just copy m_sample again. If no then follow step2.
2. copy that object definition src_sample first to target repository in 'shared' folder. Then try to copy m_sample

Comment: Thanks Koushik, actually its a mapping done by my friend, as he copied the source file of shared and exported the mapping, I couldn't open in my Informatica as am having his mapping XML file alone, I tried the steps you mentioned in here, atleast got known of some new things. Thanks ton man.